# Set Word style font to default theme font using Powershell (or VBA)

Tags: vba, powershell, ms-word

I'm writing a script to modify styles in a Word document. for each style I want to set the font to either the default 'Body' or 'Headings' style as determined by the document theme.

It's easy to set a style to a specific font:

```
# Powershell
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.Documents.Add()
$doc = $word.Documents | Select-Object -first 1

$doc.Styles["Normal"].Font.Name = "Calibri"
```

How do I set the style to either the Body or Headings font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the [`ThemeFontScheme`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.themefontscheme) of the [`DocumentTheme`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.documenttheme). There are two font properties: `MajorFont` for Headings  and `MinorFont` for Body. Each of these return a [`ThemeFonts`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.themefonts) object that is a collection of [three language fonts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msofontlanguageindex): `msoThemeLatin` for Latin font face, `msoThemeEastAsian` and `msoThemeComplexScript`. Usually only one of these returns a value, depending on the particular font. For example, Calibri only has a Latin font face.

I will assume your theme uses a Latin font face. In VBA, you can do:

```vb
doc.Styles("Normal").Font.Name = doc.DocumentTheme.ThemeFontScheme.MajorFont(msoThemeLatin).Name
```

to get the Headings font name. You can adjust accordingly for Body font. If your theme font might not have Latin font face, then you can loop through each item in the collection returned by `.MajorFont` to check which is a non-empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Since `.Minorfont(...).Name` is just a string, the cited code changes Normal style to whatever the Body theme font face is currently.  But if you then change the Body theme font definition to a different font face, Normal's face does not change with it.  To set Normal so that it follows changes in Body:

```
ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal").Font.Name = "+Body"
```

(Similar for "+Headings".) 
Normal's `.Font.Name` will still be a particular font name, like "Calibri". The setting that governs the link to +Body must be somewhere else...  I don't know how to test whether Normal is set to "Calibri" via a static font, via +Body that happens also to be "Calibri".